# cocos2dx how to create a particle System by a xml-content

Tags: c++, xml, cocos2d-x, particle-system

I have a xml-string(not the xml-file). How can I create a cocos2dx's particle-system by this xml-string?
Someone can help me. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
CCParticleSystem *pRet = new CCParticleSystem();
if(pRet)
{
    CCDictionary *dict = CCDictionary::createWithContentsOfFileThreadSafe(xmlString.c_str());
    CCAssert( dict != NULL, "Particles: file not found");

    pRet->initWithDictionary(dict);
    dict->release();
    pRet->autorelease();

    this->addChild(pRet,100);
}
```

Hope it will be helpful :)

Comment: xmlString is a 'content' but not a 'file name'

Comment: yes, it didn't work. But I have solve this problem. thank you

Comment: @minji_LT  Would you like to post your answer? It will help the people  who encounters the same problem :)

Comment: I write a function to parse the xmlContent to a CCDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It might easier to use a particle Designer and export the particle System into a plist file and use Spencer Wong's method.